# Attempting to convert two promise functions using async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

This is the prompt I am given:

**Fortune teller functions**

You'll be using the following functions provided in the ./utils/fortune-teller.js file. This library is just a way for you to practice working with promises. While you can see the source code in the file, you do not need to understand it fully or make any changes to it.

**welcome()**

The welcome() function returns a promise that, when resolved, will return a short welcome string.

*Example:*

```
welcome().then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  // "Provide me a question and I'll give you an answer..."
});
```

**goodbye()**

The goodbye() function returns a promise that, when resolved, will return a short goodbye string.

*Example:*

```
goodbye().then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  // "Best of luck in the future..."
});
```

**tell()**

The tell() function takes a string and returns a promise that, when resolved, will return a random fortune.

*Example:*

```
tell("Will the weather be warm today?").then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  // "Outlook good."
});
```

If no argument is provided, then the function will return a rejection that returns a short error message.

*Example:*

```
tell().catch((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  // "A question is required..."
});
```

**Functions to complete**

Update the getFortune() and fullSession() functions to use async and await as well as try and catch. Note that these functions require you to log statements with console.log() and should continue to do so.

Here is what I have tried:

```
const { welcome, goodbye, tell } = require("../utils/fortune-teller");

async function getFortune(question) {
  tell(question).then(msg => {
    await console.log(`Your question was: ${question}`);
    await console.log(`Your fortune is: ${msg}`)})
    .catch(err => await console.log('There was an error: A question is required...'));
}

async function fullSession(question) {
    welcome().then(msg => await console.log(msg))
    getFortune(question)
    if (!question) {
      return;
    }
    goodbye().then(msg => console.log(msg)); 
}


module.exports = { getFortune, fullSession };
```

The question also requires that you use "await" at least 4 times, and that you are *not* to use any .then or .catch statements. So I have also tried:

```
const { welcome, goodbye, tell } = require("../utils/fortune-teller");

async function getFortune(question) {
    try{
        let response = await tell(question)
        await console.log(`Your question was: ${question}`);
        await console.log(`Your fortune is: ${response}`);
    } catch (error) {
        await console.log(`There was an errror: ${error}`);
    }
 }

 async function fullSession(question) {
    try {
        let welcom = welcome();
        let fortune = getFortune(question);
        let bye = goodbye();
        let responses = await Promise.all([welcom, fortune, bye])
        console.log(responses[0]);
        console.log(responses[1]);
        console.log(responses[2]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`There was an error: ${error}`);
    }
 }

module.exports = { getFortune, fullSession };
```

I encounter more issues with the second way than I do with the first its just eliminating the .catch and .then statements that's tripping me up because it seems like no matter what adjustments I make it only makes it run worse. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Inlcuded here is also the fortune-teller.js file if anyone is interested in it:

```
const responses = require("./responses.json");

function selectRandomFortune() {
  const num = Math.random() * responses.length;
  const index = Math.floor(num);
  return responses[index];
}

function welcome() {
  const message = "Provide me a question and I'll give you an answer...";
  return Promise.resolve(message);
}

function goodbye() {
  const message = "Best of luck in the future...";
  return Promise.resolve(message);
}

function tell(question) {
  if (!question) {
    const message = "A question is required...";
    return Promise.reject(message);
  }

  const fortune = selectRandomFortune();
  return Promise.resolve(fortune);
}

module.exports = { welcome, goodbye, tell };
```

Comment: no need to `await console.log` ... since it doesn't return a Promise ... nor is it in any way asynchronous anway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go, exactly 4 awaits where they actually need to be

```
const { welcome, goodbye, tell } = require("../utils/fortune-teller");

async function getFortune(question) {
    try {
        const fortune = await tell(question);
        console.log(`Your question was: ${question}`);
        console.log(`Your fortune is: ${fortune}`); 
    } catch (err) {
        // tell rejects with "A question is required..." so just log that
        console.log(err);
    }
}

async function fullSession(question) {
    try {
        const msg = await welcome();
        console.log(msg);
        await getFortune(question);
        const response = await goodbye()
        console.log(response); 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = { getFortune, fullSession };
```

Alternative `fullSession`

```
async function fullSession(question) {
    try {
        console.log(await welcome());
        await getFortune(question);
        console.log(await goodbye()); 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i switched a couple things around, 'getFortune' it seems did require a try/catch but now the only spot where its hung up is on goodbye() the response comes back as undefined.

Comment: posted an answer so you can see the changes I made

Comment: @SwishitySwoosh - if you write the code the way I wrote it you really don't need try/catch in getFortune, because an uncaught rejection will return as rejection, and be caught in fullSession - akso, WHY would you console log the question AFTER getting the fortune - makes zero sense

Comment: ahh, I see some logic now

Comment: @SwishitySwoosh - I understand the logic now, and why try/catch in getFortune and why the question/fortune is logged in there - very sneaky question this one :p

Comment: Right?? Thanks for your help @Bravo

Answer (score 0):

so i switched a couple things around, 'getFortune' it seems did require a try/catch but now the only spot where its hung up is on goodbye() the response comes back as undefined

```
const { welcome, goodbye, tell } = require("../utils/fortune-teller");

async function getFortune(question) {
    try {
      const msg = await tell(question);
    console.log(`Your question was: ${question}`);
    console.log(`Your fortune is: ${msg}`);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('There was an error: A question is required...');
}
}

async function fullSession(question) {
    try {
        const msg = await welcome();
        console.log(msg);
        const fortune = await getFortune(question);
        console.log(`Your fortune is: ${fortune}`); 
        const response = await goodbye();
        console.log(response); 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = { getFortune, fullSession };
```

Comment: no, goodbye definitely would return  something other than undefined - at least, the goodbye you posted in your question ... and getFortune does NOT need try/catch in MY code

Comment: no, it's the getFortune that returns undefined - because you don't return anything